# Converting a custom object into JSON using JSON gem

Tags: ruby, json

I am learning how to parse and generate JSON with the JSON gem. I am easily able to create a hash of data and generate that into JSON; however, I am having a brain fart when it comes to taking a instance of a class (such as a Person instance) and putting all of its instance variables inside a hash to be converted into JSON.

This is the example I am having trouble with:

```
require "json"

class Person

  def initialize(name, age, address)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @address = address
  end

  def to_json

  end


end

p = Person.new('John Doe', 46, "123 Elm Street")
p.to_json
```

I want to create a `.to_json` method so that I can take a person object and have all of its instance variables converted into JSON. What I think I need to do is take all of the Person's instance variables, put them in a hash then call `JSON.generate(hash)`. I am having a brain fart on how to do that right now. So can someone help me complete the `to_json` method, or perhaps suggest a better way of implementing it? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Rails that helper is done for you already and you can easily get what you want running `<whatever>.to_hash` or `<whatever>.to_json`. Take a look over my source for `author_list` action: https://github.com/shybovycha/strong-sword/blob/master/app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb#L29

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to make sure you use the right basic structure:

```
def to_json(*a)
  {
    'json_class'   => self.class.name,
    'data'         => Your data
  }.to_json(*a)
end
```

The `json_class` key is used by the JSON gem to determine what class to pass the data to.  The `*a` parameter includes all the arguments that the JSON gem is passing in, generally unimportant for your classes so you just pass it straight on to the hash's `to_json` call.  Next the simplest ways to store your data are a hash or an array:

```
    'data'         => [@name, @age, @address]
```

or

```
    'data'         => { 'name' => @name, 'age' => @age, 'address' => @address
```

The first might be faster and makes the `self.json_create` method slightly easier to write, while the second is a lot easier to make backward compatible if you ever change the data structure and wish to load old JSON objects.